# Resultados aleatórios em consultas SQL sem repetir (Scroll Infinito)

Tags: php, sql-server, otimização, rolamento

Estou com esse problema há muito tempo e não consigo resolver.

Eu tenho uma página com scroll infinito que retorna algumas linhas do banco, mas os resultados na maioria das vezes repetem. Estou usando a seguinte query sempre que o scroll chega ao fim da página:

`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table_name ORDER BY NEWID()`

Para remediar a situação eu inclui uma máscara, que não retorne os resultados já exibidos na página, por exemplo:

`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN ($resultados_ja_exibidos) ORDER BY NEWID()`

Porém chega uma hora que a consulta acima fica muito lenta devido ao grande número de ids que precisam ser verificados antes de retornar os resultados.

Como faço para otimizar essa função?

Comment: Eu popularia um array com os resultados, por exemplo, você mostra por página 10 resultados, eu popularia um array com 100 resultados e desses 100, 10 iriam aparecer e assim vai, quando as requisições acabarem eu buscaria por mais 100 no banco de dados e repito o processo de popular o array, acredito que você amenizaria o acesso a base e poderia fazer a comparação com o próprio array (um array com histórico).

Comment: Eu também tentei isso. Populei um array com todos os resultados, depois passei ele para o javascript. Fui montando de 10 em 10, porém o único empecilho é que dependo 90% do desempenho do cliente. Tem como guardar em php e depois acessar aos poucos esse array ?

Comment: Sim você pode colocar um array numa Session

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Se a dada altura a tua consulta fica lenta, o problema não está na consulta, muito provavelmente está no desenho da tabela. O campo ID está indexado? Está ou pode ser marcado com `unique` ? Que outros campos passas na porção `WHERE` da tua consulta?

Comment: Sim o campo é marcado como `UNIQUE`, eu faço um `INNER JOIN` e tem mais alguns parâmetros que eu consulto como por exemplo: Status, data de expiração...

Comment: Os resultados repetem porque toda vez requisito de 10 em 10 linhas aleatoriamente. Utilizo o SQL SERVER 2008. Não existe a função `LIMIT`.

Comment: Eu costumo ordenar as consultas por id,guardo o último id e com ele faço a paginação.
Usando o id para ordenar creio que resolva seu problema.flw

Answer (score 1):

O `select` abaixo pega das linhas 1 a 20. Depois é só trocar pelos valores do offset da sua paginação para funcionar:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY uma_coluna_qualquer ) AS linha, *
    FROM      table_name 
) AS tabela_numerada
WHERE linha >= 1 AND linha < 20
ORDER BY linha
```

Melhor não usar `NEWID()`, porque ele não garante a ordem. Use um campo qualquer da tabela.